# Property of multiplation of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

I have the singular value decomposition of an image: $X = U \Sigma V^T$, where $\Sigma$ is diagonal matrix. I want to reformulate this equation like this: $X=\Sigma D$ where $D$ is any combination of $U$ and $V$. Is there efficient way for that???

Comment: Do you notice that, if $\sigma_i = 0$, the $i$ th singular value, then the $i$ th row of $\Sigma D$ is zero...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rewrite the equation in that form. The reason there are matrices $U,V$ in the singular value decomposition is that in general one needs them in order to reduce "what remains" of $X$ to just a diagonal matrix, which is a very restricted form. With just a right-multiplication allowed, one cannot in general make this work with the diagonal matrix$~\Sigma$.